# There is no endomorphism $\phi : \mathbb R^5 \to \mathbb R^5$ with $\ker \phi = \text{Im}\phi$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Is it true, that we haven't any linear mappings (Let it be called $\phi$) between $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, where $n = 5$ and Ker $\ \phi$ = Im$\ \phi$

Where:

Ker $\ \phi = \{v \  | \ \phi(v) = 0, v \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$

Im$\ \phi = \{\phi(v) \  | \ v \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$

Comment: It is true and it follows pretty much directly from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem .

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem? Also, you need the fact that dimensions of (finite-dimensional) vector spaces are **nonnegative integers**.

Answer (score 0):

According to  [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) this would lead to the contradiction

$$\dim \ker \phi + \dim \text{Im} \phi = 2\dim \ker \phi = 5$$